# How to upload multiple images to server using Dio?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
CreatePostImage(String author,List<File> images) async {
  try {
    String imagename;
    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      'author' : author.toString(),
      'MediaImageArray': [
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {imagename = images[i].path.split('/').last,
          await MultipartFile.fromFile(images[i].path, filename: imagename), }
      ]});
 
    Response response = await Dio().post("$SERVER_IP/api/articles/", data: formData);
    print(response.toString());
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

I tried this code but it posts null value to the server.Anybody that knows the solution?

**Update**

```
{"id":"bb1936af-01ad-4873-ad14-7dc3aedee632","author":"d39d29c8-4807-41c5-a3fa-e9cb117fdb2d","MediaImageArray":null}
```

This is the output i get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pub.dev/packages/dio#sending-formdata)

```
FormData.fromMap({
    "files": [
      MultipartFile.fromFileSync("./example/upload.txt",
          filename: "upload.txt"),
      MultipartFile.fromFileSync("./example/upload.txt",
          filename: "upload.txt"),
    ]
  });
```

So in your case you will have something like this :

```
CreatePostImage(String author,List<File> images) async {
  try {
    String imagename;
    FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
      'author' : author.toString(),
      'MediaImageArray': images.map((item)=> MultipartFile.fromFileSync(item.path,
          filename: item.path.split('/').last)).toList()
});
 
    Response response = await Dio().post("$SERVER_IP/api/articles/", data: formData);
    print(response.toString());
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: Same error.Do you think it is from server part or flutter? Because the code you gave to me looks fine and gives no error.I posted the output in the update

Comment: Try to use ```Postman``` to call the same api and see if it works or not to be sure if it is from flutter or the server

Comment: thanks a lot.I call this case solved.Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: This comment saved my ass after trying to upload multiple images using DIO multipart for several days. Thanks bro

Answer (score -1):

Your original code is wrong just because you are using scope for `for` loop.